# PHP: Shared variables in classes / instances

Tags: php, oop

I have a Core class which is extended by two other classes (Ctrl and Main).
I would like to call Ctrl out of Main. Ctrl should set a variable which is then usable in Main.

The code below demonstrates the structure. You can also test it here: https://www.tehplayground.com/7Xae6rEv7WakfQIe

The expected output would be 123 but it is 0

```
class Core {
    public $myvar = 0;
}

class Ctrl extends Core {
    public function setMyVar($val) {
        $this->myvar = $val;
    }
}

class Main extends Core {
    public function do() {
        $ctrl = new Ctrl;
        $ctrl->setMyVar(123);
        var_dump($this->myvar);
    }
}

$main = new Main;
$main->do();
```

Requirement: The initialization of Ctrl should happen inside of the class Main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've created a whole new instance of `Ctrl`? 
Variables are not shared between instances, unless u'd use `static` ones

```php
<?php

class Core {
    public static $myvar = 0;
}

class Ctrl extends Core {
    public function setMyVar($val) {
        self::$myvar = $val;
    }
}

class Main extends Core {
    public function do() {
        $ctrl = new Ctrl;
        $ctrl->setMyVar(123);
        var_dump(self::$myvar);
    }
}

$main = new Main;
$main->do();
```

[demo](https://www.tehplayground.com/MSRuYVTVsMmsjhqi)